# Background process to capture user specified files

Tags: java, search, background-process, system-tray

I need to create an application that should reside in the tray and a process should be running to capture some files that is been specified by the user. I want to develop this application using java. How could i do this?

Comment: Java is not a good choice for that since it is platform independent and putting something in the Windows tray is very platform dependent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java6 has a [SystemTray](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/) API that may be helpful.

Comment: I know i can use system tray. but can i make it as a process that keeps executing whenever a user starts. how do i do that?